# Conditional formatting range based on 2 conditions (other cell's format/ value)

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-statements

I'm new to VBA and English isn't my native language so here goes.

I want to conditional format rows/ range (giving them green-colored background) if cell C in that row have duplicate value in column C and also if there's a cell in column O that equals 0, but if the cell in column C has no similar value, don't apply the conditional format to that cell (eventhough cells in column O has the value of 0).

Note: Cells that have same values in column C will always be above and below each other, for example it's possible that C1=C2=C3 but not C1<>C2, C1=C3

I know I'm not explaining it clearly, so please just let me know if you want more information.

Update (more information): I may have 3 or more rows with same C column value above and below each other, and the zero value in column O will always be the bottom row.

Example:
If C1=C2=C3=C4=C5 and O5=0 , Rows 1 2 3 4 5 become green colored.
I prefer using conditional format even if it needs vba code so I dont have to run it everytime there's new 0 in column O.

I've used this code but it doesn't work (obviously), but maybe it's a little different with my question because the real data is more complicated than what I illustrated. My data table starts at 4th row (header on 3rd). This code only formats 1 row (above the row that has zero column O value) and what I need is all rows with same column C value are formatted. Please keep in mind that I'm a newbie in vba :(

```
With Range("A4:r8000").FormatConditions.Add( _ 
Type:=xlExpression, _
 Formula1:="=AND($C4=$C5,$O5=0,$F4<>0)")
 .Interior.Color = 13551615
 .Font.Color = -16383844
End With
```

Comment: I use this code, but maybe it's a little different with my question because the real data is more complicated than what I illustrated. My data table starts at 4th row (header on 3rd). This code only formats 1 row (above the row that has zero column O value) and what I need is all rows with same column C value are formatted. Please keep in mind that I'm a newbie in vba :(

With Range("A4:r8000").FormatConditions.Add( _
        Type:=xlExpression, _
        Formula1:="=AND($C4=$C5,$O5=0,$F4<>0)")
    
        .Interior.Color = 13551615
        .Font.Color = -16383844
    
    End With

Comment: Can you format the code and put it in the original question body to make it easier to read (and easier to help you)? [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) has a guide to help format.

Comment: Okay done, please check it out

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will go through and highlight duplicate cells if any of the duplicate cells' rows have '0' in column O. I am still working on a way that will make this auto update whenever a change happens in Column O, but can't quite figure that out. Will update when I do.

```
Sub ConditionalFormatSE()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim myCell As Range
Dim colCVals As Range

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

Set colCVals = Range("C1", "C" & lastRow)

colCVals.clearformats

For Each myCell In colCVals
    If Cells(myCell.Row, 15).Value = "0" Then
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(colCVals, myCell.Value) > 1 Then
            Set c = colCVals.Find(myCell.Value)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                firstAddress = c.Address
                Do
                    c.Interior.color = RGB(198, 239, 206)
                    c.Font.color = RGB(0, 97, 0)
                    Set c = colCVals.FindNext(c)
                Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next myCell

Set colCVals = Nothing
Set myCell = Nothing
Set c = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

As for making it run automatically, put this in: VBAProject([workbookname].xlsm)->Microsoft Excel Objects->Sheet1([sheetname]) and it should run whenever a value in column 'O' is changed

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range

Set KeyCells = Columns(15)

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
       Call ConditionalFormatSE
End If

Set KeyCells = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: It works Sir, but one little thing, can you change it so not only cells in column C are highlighted but also the adjacent cells in the data table. My table ranges from column A to R

Comment: If whoever downvoted could mention why, that would be fantastic. I believe I answered the question to the best of my ability. To answer Kheuwnyuk, you should be able to change `c.Interior.color` to `Range(Cells(c.row, 1), Cells(c.row, 18)).Interior.color` and similar for `c.font.color`. I am not able to test it now, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as the formula for the CFR,

```
=and(countif(c:c, c1)>1, o1=0, len(o1))
'alternate for part that I am not sure I understand
=and(countif(c$1:c1, c1)>1, o1=0, len(o1))
```

Answer (score -1):

If cells with same values are always grouped (one below the other), following code might do what you want.

```
Sub Test()
Dim lLastRow As Long
Dim i As Integer

lLastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lLastRow
    If ((Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value) And (Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 15).Value = "0")) Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbGreen
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried it but your code doesn't work for me because I may have 3 or more rows with same column C values but only the bottom has zero value in the column O. For example if I have 4 rows with same C column value (C1=C2=C3=C4) and the bottom has 0 values in column O (O4=0), I want all the 4 rows turn to green.